# Visual Basic Or, OrElse still returning false

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, basic

I am new to VB.net and i have little problem with this statement, i want to throw msgBox just if in txtBox txtTitul is not "Bc." or "" or "Ing." ... 
and this is throwing msgBox everytime

```
If Not txtTitul.Text.Equals("Bc.") _
    OrElse Not txtTitul.Text.Equals("") _
    OrElse Not txtTitul.Text.Equals("Bc.") _
    OrElse Not txtTitul.Text.Equals("Mgr.") _
    OrElse Not txtTitul.Text.Equals("Ing.") _
    OrElse Not txtTitul.Text.Equals("Mgr. art.") _
    OrElse Not txtTitul.Text.Equals("Ing. arch.") _
    OrElse Not txtTitul.Text.Equals("MUDr.") _
    OrElse Not txtTitul.Text.Equals("MVDr.") _
    OrElse Not txtTitul.Text.Equals("RNDr.") _
    OrElse Not txtTitul.Text.Equals("PharmDr.") _
    OrElse Not txtTitul.Text.Equals("PhDr.") _
    OrElse Not txtTitul.Text.Equals("JUDr.") _
    OrElse Not txtTitul.Text.Equals("PaedDr.") _
    OrElse Not txtTitul.Text.Equals("ThDr.") Then
    MsgBox("Neplatny titul!")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to use `OrElse` but `AndAlso`, because only if it's not one of those it's an invalid title (so not 1st **and** not 2nd **and** not 3rd **and** so on....).

But can i show you a much simpler and more maintainable approach?

```
Dim allowedTitles = {"Bc.","Ing.","Ing. arch.","MUDr.","MVDr.","RNDr.","PhDr.","PaedDr.","ThDr."}
If Not allowedTitles.Contains(txtTitul.Text) Then 
    MsgBox("Invalid title!")
End If
```

If you also want to accept lower-case, so ignore the case, you can use:

```
If Not allowedTitles.Contains(txtTitul.Text, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then 
    MsgBox("Invalid title!")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider your input is "Bc."

```
Not txtTitul.Text.Equals("Bc.")  <- false
Not txtTitul.Text.Equals("")     <- true
false OrElse true = true
```

Consider your input is "abc"

```
Not txtTitul.Text.Equals("Bc.")  <- true
Not txtTitul.Text.Equals("")     <- true
true OrElse true = true
```

For solution, you may consider Tim's answer.